# ubuntu mysql 5.6.30 reinstall

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

my mysql configuration files have become corrupt (due to being deleted).
How can i re-install / repair my mysql installation without losing the database?

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ **has been deleted**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-200:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d$ sudo service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance:
start: Job failed to start
```

Comment: A good start would be restoring your backup.

Comment: there is no server backup.

Comment: Copy data files to another place, re-install MySQL package, copy data files back in.